# How do i use multiple AMPScript functions for a single variable?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a variable that that is pulling from another variable and applying the `Field` function to it as below.

```
set @CampaignStartTime = Field(@CampTypeRows,"Event_Time_Text__c")
```

I now want to apply the function `SystemDateToLocalDate` to the line above to make the time output localised.

I tried the below but keep getting validation issues:

```
set @CampaignStartTime = SystemDateToLocalDate(Field(@CampTypeRows,"Event_Time_Text__c"))
```

Also, worth mentioning I have another block further down the email which is setting new variables using `@CampaignStartTime`. Will any changes impact my second block?

```
   set @GoogleStartEndTime = (CONCAT(
   Format(@CampaignDate, "yyyyMMdd")),
   'T',
   Format(@CampaignStartTime, "HHmm"),
   '00Z',
   '%2f',
   Format(@CampaignDate, "yyyyMMdd"),
   'T',
   Format(@CampaignEndTime, "HHmm"),
   '00Z'   
  )
```

What am I doing wrong? and How can I fix it?

Comment: I would also make sure 'Event_Time_Text__c' is actually a date field. The name implies it's a text version of a date which isn't compatible with date functions.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect, not having your complete Ampscript, the issue is caused by you not selecting a single row, but applying `Field` function to multiple rows. Here is what you need to do:

```
SET @rowCount = rowcount(@CampTypeRows) /* count rows to ensure your lookup returns something */

IF @rowCount > 0 THEN /* only execute this block if you have some results */

  SET @row = row(@CampTypeRows,1) /* get row #1 */
  SET @CampaignStartTime = SystemDateToLocalDate(Field(@row,"Event_Time_Text__c")) /* Convert your date */

ENDIF
```

Your AmpScript further down the page will work without issues.

Comment: @MJB - remember to mark the answer as accepted